# Concatenate two variables to check null condition using JSTL tags

Tags: spring-boot, jstl

I am trying to send image of each user separately in ModelMap

```
model.addAttribute("profileImage"+i, sb); // I have added attribute in loop
```

Variable 'i' is an index for each image which I am iterating for each user.

Now I am Having ***profileImage0,profileImage1,profileImage2*** and so on.

While Accessing I am putting some condition

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${profileImage!=null}">
    <center><img src="${profileImage}"  id="${profileImage}" class="rounded-circle img-circle img-responsive" style="height:90px;width:90px;" alt="Avatar">
    </c:when> 
    <c:otherwise>
    <center><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/defaultuserprofile.png"  id="${profileImage}" class="rounded-circle img-circle img-responsive" style="height:90px;width:90px;" alt="Avatar"></center>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

So in the Above Code I need to **append some indexing to a variable** which will first initialize the value of a variable then use it properly instead using like this one.

like profileImage0,profileImage1 and so on....

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`<c:forEach>`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm) tag to iterate over your variables. You may want to pass in the maximum number of values you have in your controller so you know how many values you need to pick up from your request:

```
<c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "${max}">
  <c:set var = "variableName" scope = "session" value = "profileName + ${i}"/>
  <c:set var = "profileImage" scope = "session" value = "${variableName}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

(or something like that...)